# Asp.net Identity 2.0 with LDAP repository

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap, asp.net-identity

As I knew, LDAP repository can manage millions of users read in a efficient way. In Asp.net MVC5, the default Identity Framework is binding with MS-SQL server. Is there a way to use LDAP repository to instead of MS-SQL server?